# Why do we drop terms from BigO notation if our data sets aren't infinite?

Tags: big-o

Maybe I am just completely missing something, but why do we drop terms from BigO notation if our data sets aren't infinite?

In an infinite data set it makes sense that n << 20n << n log n

But in the real world data sets aren't infinite.
Say we have 1 trillion elements. An algorithm with BigO(n * log(n)) time complexity would take 12x longer than a BigO(n) algorithm
(1000000000000*log(1000000000000))/1000000000000 = 12

So if we have an algorithm with a time complexity of BigO(20n) why would we drop the 20 constant when an algorithm with 20n time complexity would take longer than the n*log(n) time complexity algorithm on the 1 trillion element data set?

terrible code examples below

```
fun badFunction1(someData: List<Int>) {
    someData.sort()
}
```

```
fun badFunction2(someData: List<Int>) {
    for (number in 1..20) {
        for (index in 1..someData.count()) {
            println(someData[index])
        }
    }

}
```

```
fun badFunction3(someData: List<Int>) {
    for (index in 1..someData.count()) {
        println(someData[index])
    }
}
```

I'm confused since in the above examples with 1 trillion data points badFunction3 < badFunction1 < badFunction2 but BigO would give badFunction3 = BadFunction2 < badFunction1

Why wouldn't you need to estimate the size of your data set, and the number of times the operation would need to be run before you could determine the breakpoint where you could drop terms from your BigO evaluation?

If BigO just expresses growth rates trending towards infinity, why do we care about it at all instead of trying to figure out actual computations performed? To be open I've been coding professionally for years, and I've never used BigO other than interviews so it just seems completely worthless to me.

Comment: Big O isn't meant to tell you whether one algorithm will be faster than another for a particular number of elements. That depends on many more factors than can be captured in a simple expression. It tells you how your algorithm scales as you give it more elements to work on. Your linear `O(20n)` might start off expensive, but it's only going to get worse linearly. An `O(2^n)` might start off being really cheap for a small number of elements, but it's going to get expensive fast, as you add more elements.

Comment: (Also as a side note: log is normally taken to be base 2 here. Big O expressions with log in them tend to be divide-and-conquer. The base doesn't matter in big O notation though, as changing the base just changes it by a constant factor)

Comment: Why do we care about BigO then if our number of elements will almost always be semi well defined?  Well defined being zero to 1 trillion even

Comment: Because big-o notation makes the maths sooo much easier. In general all of these notations (little-o, omega) allow us to ignore the details that don't have a big impact on the problem. The only way we can define "don't have a big impact" is by their lack of effect on the asymptotic behaviour. However, as you say, a smaller big-O doesn't imply a faster program. A smaller omega doesn't even define a faster program if you limit the input size.

Comment: When you care about this stuff, the number of elements normally isn't well defined. An algorithm might work perfectly fine in your development environment, with what you think are sensible inputs, and then bring production down that one time it's exposed to more than it can handle. Big O tells you how likely that is to happen. A linear algorithm is normally fine: if it's fine in dev, its probably fine in prod, even if the overheads are high. An exponential algorithm is so explosive you need to be really careful about what you expose it to, and put limits on its inputs...

Comment: ... Quadratic normally falls in that sweet spot where its cheap enough that you don't notice any problems in dev, but expensive enough with larger inputs that it goes on to cause a problem in prod at some point down the line

Comment: I think it's just something you always need to have in the back of your mind as a senior dev. If you spot a nested loop, that's probably quadratic, so you just want to check what the upper bound is: oh, it's user-defined, we probably want to refactor that... This other bit of code uses a dictionary lookup, even though it might strictly be cheaper to use a linear search in most cases: but the overheads are low and it will probably scale well, so no need to worry. Oh dear, this looks exponential and I bet it was never tested with more than a few elements: flag it in review!

Comment: It's also something to bear in mind when writing a bit of code. E.g. logically, is it *possible* to write something that is linear or log-linear: if so, is it sensible to implement an algorithm with that complexity? Don't just dive in and write something, and then move on without just thinking about whether there's a hidden complexity there. Code with low algorithmic complexity *tends* to be neater and easier to read and understand in my experience, although that's not universally ture